# hierarchyid / SSIS / memory variable

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014, hierarchyid

I realize that I can convert a hierarchyid to a string variable, and store it as a string in an SSIS memory variable.  what I can't figure out is a bulk insert within SSIS, and use the memory variable to insert it into a table with the column typed as hierarchyid ...

I could store it as a string, but that doesn't feel right...

I can't find anything regarding SSIS and hierarchyid except for the SQL Wizard, but that does apply here as I have my own custom package.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Help me understand "use the memory variable" part of your question, would you?

Comment: I'm using FileTable which uses a primary key of a hierarchid.  I use this key to track the file that I am processing - provides traceability from import to destination.  I use a for next loop to loop through the files that were selected, processing each one. Standard pattern for moving data from a select statement, into a object memory variable (at least that is what I learned).

Comment: Richard, I've used SSIS for years and I'm totally confused on what you're asking here. Maybe you could post some screen shots and/or more detailed workflow information on how to recreate the issue over here. Screen shots would be the best and quickest way to get your problem resolved.